# Unable to get property 'showmodaldialog' of undefined or null reference

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I got "unable to get property 'showmodaldialog' of undefined or null reference" error when I try to open the list displayform in SharePoint 2013 modal dialog.

This is my script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function openDialog( pUrl ) {  
         SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(   
         {  
          url: pUrl,
         width: 650,  
         height:600,  
         title: "MyTitle"
          }  
         );  
    }  
</script>
```

Calling:

```
<a href="javascript:openDialog('../../News/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID={@ows_ID}')"><xsl:value-of select="@ows_LinkTitle"/></a>
```

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening because `SP.UI.Dialog.js` file is not loaded. Modify your code as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openDialog( pUrl ) {  
        var options = {
            url: pUrl,
            width: 650,  
            height:600,  
            title: "MyTitle"
        };
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: Would you happen to know why just  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options); worked on my computer, but not to the rest of the company?